# Converting excel spreadsheet to json

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I want to convert an excel spreadsheet data to a JSON file. Here is the code I currently have:

**Data**
[excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csvmw.png)

**Code**

```
import xlrd 
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('./file1.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

```
data_list = []
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    data['name'] = row_values[0]
    data['description'] = row_values[1]
    data_list.append(data)
data_list = {'columns': data_list}
j = json.dumps(data_list)
with open('seq1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

**Output**

```
{"columns": [{"name": "FILEID", "description": "FILETYPE"}]}
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "fileid",
      "description": "FILEID"
    },
    {
      "name": "filetype",
      "description": "FILETYPE"
    },
    {
      "name": "stusab",
      "description": "STUSAB"
    },
    {
      "name": "chariter",
      "description": "CHARITER"
    },
    {
      "name": "sequence",
      "description": "SEQUENCE"
    },
    {
      "name": "logrecno",
      "description": "LOGRECNO"
    }
],
```

The "name" column should be displaying the first row while the "description" column should be displaying the second row.

What modification can I do in my function to get the output I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over columns, not rows

```
import xlrd 
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('./file1.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

data_list = []
data = OrderedDict()

for colnum in range(0, sh.ncols):    
    data['name'] = sh.row_values(0)[colnum]
    data['description'] = sh.row_values(1)[colnum]
    data_list.append(data.copy())

data_list = {'columns': data_list}
j = json.dumps(data_list)
with open('seq1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense and not sure why I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to:

```
import excel2json

excel2json.convert_from_file('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: I am aware of this library but I would like my function to be flexible enough to add more columns as I move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./file1.xlsx')
with open('seq1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_json())
```